# I am trying to find the third Tuesday for February, June and July in C#

Tags: c#

Can I use one method for the three months or should I use three different methods? Here's my code:

```
public DateTime ThirdMonday(DateTime thirdMonday)
{
    int mondayDay= (from day in Enumerable.Range(1, 31)
                     where new DateTime(thirdMonday.Year, thirdMonday.Month, day).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday
                     select day).ElementAt(3);
    mondayDay = new DateTime(thirdMonday.Year, thirdMonday.Month, mondayDay);
    return thirdMonday;
}
```

Comment: It's not obvious what your parameter is meant to be. Personally I'd write a method with a signature of `public DateTime GetOccurrenceInMonth(int year, int month, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, int occurrence)`. And yes, you can absolutely write that in C#. (It's simpler in Noda Time, particularly Noda Time 2.0, but...)

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer, but declaring `int mondayDay` then assigning the result of `new DateTime` to it is surely isn't correct. And you should return the result of the `new`, not a copy of the input parameter!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and then follow @Jon Skeet remarks for improvements:

```
    public static DateTime ThirdMonday(DateTime thirdMonday, DateTime month) {
            var mondayDay = (from day in Enumerable.Range(1, 31)
                             where new DateTime(thirdMonday.Year, month.Month, day).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
                             select day).ElementAt(2);
            var result = new DateTime(thirdMonday.Year, thirdMonday.Month, mondayDay);
            return result;
        }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = ThirdMonday(DateTime.Now, new DateTime(2016, 2, 1)); //pass February as the month
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I worry sometimes for our furture - folks are finding all sorts of ways to use LINQ expressions and other complex algorithms for things that can be solved with simple maths.

You certainly dont need to interate over each day of the month to figure it out!

```
public DateTime GetOccurrenceInMonth(int year, int month, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, int occurance)
{
    var dtFirst = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    var dowFirstDay = (int)dtFirst.DayOfWeek;
    var day  = (occurance*7)+1 - ( (dowFirstDay-(int)dayOfWeek+7)%7 );
    return new DateTime(year, month, day);
}
```